# Understanding Kirchhoff's theorem

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to the understand the [Kirchhoff's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem) and it seems to be giving a hard time. Basically how do you explain why you have $n^{n-2}$ in finding the number of cycles in a given graph. A very basic explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cayley's formula counts the number of distinct labeled trees of a complete graph $K_n$.  the number of spanning trees is equal to any cofactor of the Laplacian matrix of $K_n$. The Laplacian matrix is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  n-1 & -1      & \cdots & -1      \\
  -1  & n-1     & \cdots & -1      \\ 
  \vdots & \vdots& \ddots & \vdots \\ 
  -1 & -1      & \cdots & n-1      \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Any cofactor of the above matrix is $n^{n−2}$.